# Trying to deploy on heroku but encounter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am fresh with ruby on rails and I've been trying to deploy to heroku using git but I encounter error.

My working environment is windows but using WSL to run ruby code in a ubuntu environment.

This is the content my gem file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

group :production, :test do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
# include the httparty
gem 'httparty'
```

and after running `git push heroku master` i got this error

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.6
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.6
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
       Installing rake 12.0.0
       Installing i18n 0.7.0
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
       Installing minitest 5.10.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
       Installing rack 2.0.1
       Installing nio4r 1.2.1 with native extensions
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
       Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
       Installing arel 7.1.4
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Installing method_source 0.8.2
       Installing thor 0.19.4
       Installing multi_xml 0.6.0
       Installing multi_json 1.12.1
       Installing pg 0.19.0 with native extensions
       Installing puma 3.6.2 with native extensions
       Using bundler 1.13.6
       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5
       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5
       Installing sass 3.4.23
       Installing tilt 2.0.5
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing nokogiri 1.7.0.1 with native extensions
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing sprockets 3.7.1
       Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4 with native extensions
       Installing mime-types 3.1
       Installing uglifier 3.0.4
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing httparty 0.14.0
       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
       Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
       Installing activesupport 5.0.1
       Installing mail 2.6.4
       Installing globalid 0.3.7
       Installing activemodel 5.0.1
       Installing jbuilder 2.6.1
       Installing activejob 5.0.1
       Installing activerecord 5.0.1
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.2
       Installing loofah 2.0.3
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing actionview 5.0.1
       Installing actionpack 5.0.1
       Installing actionmailer 5.0.1
       Installing actioncable 5.0.1
       Installing railties 5.0.1
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.0
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.1
       Installing rails 5.0.1
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.6
       Installing jquery-rails 4.2.2
       Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 58 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from httparty:
       When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
       Bundle completed (25.45s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Detecting rake tasks
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:305:in `lock': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:130:in `lock'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `setup'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
 !     from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
 !     from vendor/bundle/bin/rake:15:in `<main>'
 !
/app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:102:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
/tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/definition.rb:305:in `lock': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:130:in `lock'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `setup'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `rescue in require'
    from /tmp/build_ddb3a86a41cea80627a32fcab8b349c2/vendor/ruby-2.2.6/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from vendor/bundle/bin/rake:15:in `<main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:777:in `rake'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:77:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:70:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:798:in `allow_git'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:100:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:89:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:49:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:47:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:38:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:37:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:41:in `block in compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:48:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:44:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:40:in `compile'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:16:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/base.rb:131:in `log'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:15:in `block in <main>'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /app/tmp/buildpacks/f6d48d8a14fccbb19c0c0402fca224929d18e9ee042b3e204bc5992612e990d3b3a0fb1f9627b1a3bae11e9fa20dffc96e136bd734a2f3cf92a0d05bedd42cfe/bin/compile:11:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

What to do with it? Can you help?

I tried running `bundle exec rake -P` and this is the result

```
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake)
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:305:in `lock'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:130:in `lock'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `setup'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

Comment: The problem doesn't appear to be in your Gemfile
`Bundle completed (25.45s)
Cleaning up the bundler cache.`
Do you have any custom rake tasks?

Comment: I tried to run `bundle exec rake -P` but this result to `bundler: failed to load command: rake (/home/fil/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/bin/rake)` siimilar to above errors.

Comment: How similar? Can you post the full output of `bundle exec rake -P`?

Comment: Just a note (but likely not the source of the problem): when running Rails 5 you don't need the `12factor` gem.

Comment: did you try? > RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

Comment: It looks like you may have an issue with your rails or gem installations. Are you using rvm or rbenv (or other) to manage ruby?

Comment: @Drenmi thanks man it works

Comment: The suggestion of Drenmi solved the problem

Comment: Cool! I added it as an answer for others to find. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Rails 5, you no longer need the `rails_12factor` gem.

> Previous versions of Rails required you to add a gem to your project
>   `rails_12factor` to enable static asset serving and logging on Heroku.
>   If you are deploying a new application this gem is not needed.